# Angular Installation Failing due to ENOENT Error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm trying to install angular. I've been following the installation steps mentioned, however running `npm install -g @angular/cli`, I run into the following error.
[image]

The following is my version of node and npm.
[image]

I'm on a 32-bit, Windows 7 operating system.

**Edit 1**:
Below is the error log that gets saved.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'E:\\Nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Nanda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose npm-session aa9c7864071a84f9
.
.
.
75 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\d74359a7' -> 'C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1a\94\b0bf25ce70e3a557bd2f6e7ce38f87d6e715bf15d505ea7404b7510dcbb9b86427338b5fbf6ee5543c0aa619fab39ec391345cd432372d4c8a7c6bdb6e09'
76 verbose cwd C:\Users\Nanda
77 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
78 verbose argv "E:\\Nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Nanda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
79 verbose node v12.16.3
80 verbose npm  v6.14.5
81 error code ENOENT
82 error syscall rename
83 error path C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\d74359a7
84 error dest C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1a\94\b0bf25ce70e3a557bd2f6e7ce38f87d6e715bf15d505ea7404b7510dcbb9b86427338b5fbf6ee5543c0aa619fab39ec391345cd432372d4c8a7c6bdb6e09
85 error errno -4058
86 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\d74359a7' -> 'C:\Users\Nanda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1a\94\b0bf25ce70e3a557bd2f6e7ce38f87d6e715bf15d505ea7404b7510dcbb9b86427338b5fbf6ee5543c0aa619fab39ec391345cd432372d4c8a7c6bdb6e09'
87 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
88 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

**Edit 2**:However, I tried installing the express package globally and it was installed successfully.

Comment: Try to run the terminal as administrator and check it

Comment: Looks like an NPM cache error. Try `npm cache verify` then retry installing Angular

Comment: I tried to run as administrator, and also tried ```npm cache verify``` and reinstalled. Both of the solutions did not work.I get the same error as in the first image above.

Answer (score 0):

hey u are under E: drive   try to install angular under C:
somove to C:drive You can do cd C:\ to change to C
then npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: `npm install -g` is a global command, doesn't matter which drive you run it from.